# Exception in thread django-main-thread

Tags: python, django

I was implementing google login by using oauth2client library and did some change in `/google-login/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oauth2client/contrib/django_util/__init__.py`
just replaced `from django.core import urlresolvers` to `from django.urls import reverse` and Line 411 `urlresolvers.reverse(...)` to `reverse(...)`
While running my server
python manage.py runserver
A typeError occured
Trace back of this error is:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/akshay/django/google_login/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/akshay/django/google_login/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/akshay/django/google_login/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'doc' and 'pos'
```

Got this traceback
I have no clue what does it mean.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/akshay/django/google_login/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/akshay/django/google_login/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/akshay/django/google_login/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/akshay/django/google_login/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/akshay/django/google_login/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/akshay/django/google_login/login/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from oauth2client.contrib.django_util.models import CredentialsField
  File "/home/akshay/django/google_login/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/contrib/django_util/__init__.py", line 365, in <module>
    oauth2_settings = OAuth2Settings(django.conf.settings)
  File "/home/akshay/django/google_login/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/contrib/django_util/__init__.py", line 341, in __init__
    info = _get_oauth2_client_id_and_secret(settings_instance)
  File "/home/akshay/django/google_login/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/contrib/django_util/__init__.py", line 277, in _get_oauth2_client_id_and_secret
    return _load_client_secrets(secret_json)
  File "/home/akshay/django/google_login/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/contrib/django_util/__init__.py", line 255, in _load_client_secrets
    client_type, client_info = clientsecrets.loadfile(filename)
  File "/home/akshay/django/google_login/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 165, in loadfile
    return _loadfile(filename)
  File "/home/akshay/django/google_login/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 122, in _loadfile
    obj = json.load(fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 451 (char 450)
```

Comment: Try running runserver with `--noreload`, you might get the actual exception and traceback.

Comment: I tried and got that..(2nd traceback)

Comment: The second traceback looks like there's a syntax error in the Google credentials JSON file (so it's not valid JSON). That might be the root cause for the other exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a syntax error in my client_secrets.json file.
After fixing, it worked.
Thanks AKX for pointing out.

Answer (score -1):

This issue can also be caused by making any changes in ny of the core django files

Answer (score -1):

For those who are facing a similar problem and land on this page.

Go to your settings.py and make sure you have a comma at the end of each lines in your installed apps, Middleware etc...

Answer (score -3):

Try installing Postgres if you are using one.
If already installed try - pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).